# Get last slash of string python

Tags: python

I have a string which I split in a list on spaces, one of the items in the list is for example, this: `"/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py"`

The end result I want is to make it come out like this:

```
window.py="/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py"
```

In Javascript I would do something like:

```
var string = "/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py";
for (var i = string.length; i>1; i--)
{
    if(string.charAt(i) === "/")
    {
        temp = string.substring(i+1, string.length);
        string = temp + "=" + '"' + string + '"';
        console.log(string);
        i = 0;
    }
}
>>> window.py="/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py"
```

But for loops don't work this way in Python, I've seen some for loops with `enemurate` but I don't understand how I can implement that with what I want. 
In the end I want to go through the entire list with `for split in splits` and concatenate the results into one string

Comment: Why don't for loops work this way? `for i in range(len(str)-1,1,-1):`

Comment: Re: `window.py=...` Do you have an object named `window` with an attribute `py`? I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function to properly split the path is `os.path.split(path)`. It will make sure the split will be done at the right divider for the OS it runs on.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.split('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py')
('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy', 'window.py')
>>> os.path.split('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py')[1]
'window.py'
```

There is also a convenience function to do it in one step:

```
>>> os.path.basename('/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py')
'window.py'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get everything after the last `/` with:

```
"/home/hoeter/PycharmProjects/Renpy/window.py".split('/')[-1]
```